# My php form is inserting blank rows in my SQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Below is my code:
Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
<?php

include("secure/connect.php");

//Confirm document reading
$document = $_POST["document"]; 
$user_name = $_POST["p_name"]; 
$confirmation = $_POST["confirm"]; 
$comment = $_POST["query"];

$insert="INSERT INTO documentconfirmation (document,p_name,confirm,query) VALUES 
  ('$document', '$user_name','$confirmation','$comment')";

$result3 =mysqli_query($conn,$insert) or die (mysqli_error($conn));?>'
```

Comment: Are you using the same script to display the form and process the submission? Then you need to check that the form was submitted with something like `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: Replace `submit` with the name of the submit button in the form.

Comment: Perhaps validate / sanitize the variables as well before inserting them into the database.

Comment: A couple of common causes for this are not setting the form method to post, and not naming or misnaming the form inputs. (Assuming the request is a form submission.)

Comment: And see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a prepared statement. As a rule of thumb I would *always* use prepared statements even in development code as 
A) They are usually designed with good, self documenting interfaces which results in cleaner - more understandable - code, and 
B) It means you do not have to refactor your code base before production (you had better not be using unprepared statements in production)

Doing this with the mysqli driver in php (using OOP)

```php
// Constructor the statement object
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO documentconfirmation (document,p_name,confirm,query) VALUES 
      (?, ?, ?, ?)");

// Bind parameters ssbs stands for string-string-bool-string
$stmt->bind_param('ssbs', $document, $user_name, $confirmation, $comment);
// Execute the statement
$stmt->execute();
```

I would also check that the values are not null for any of those variables as that is likely another problem and caused by improper posting to the script